is there any way to fetch name of renamed file in jmeter? It passes current Epoch I guess when I fetch the name
I Rename & Move 20 files from one folder to another folder via Jmeter OS Process Sampler.
i.e. TestFile.docx to TestFile-${__time(,postfix)}.docx
TestFile_2008202416202205.docx

I use TestFile-${postfix}.docx to get the file name.
Now the problem is when I use TestFile-${postfix}.docx this to fetch the file name, in ${postfix} it passes different filename instead of TestFile_2008202416202205.docx
Like, It finds TestFile_200820241123343.docx instead of TestFile_2008202416202205.docx
Its due to ${postfix} is there any way to fetch name of that renamed file?
See this screenshot,


I fail to see where do you declare this ${postfix} variable.
You need to change this guy:
TestFile-${__time(,)}.docx

to this one:
TestFile-${__time(,postfix)}.docx

this way you will be able to refer the generated value later on:

You can use Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination in order to see which JMeter Variables are being set with their respective values.

I am using the same TestFile-${__time(,postfix)}.docx. Sorry Edited my question. File gets renamed but in next request when I pass TestFile-${postfix}.docx to get the name of that file it passes different name in the request.
For ex. File is renamed to TestFile-12342024.docx then it passes TestFile-123234243.docx like this. I mean Epoch changed while passing. @IvanG
